# Validating POST JSON body matches struct

Tags: go, post, struct, mux

I'm having trouble validating if JSON body passed to my POST endpoints matches the struct created for the acceptable JSON body. Any help would be appreciated

```golang
type NewUser struct {
    UserID   string `json:"user_id"`
    UserName string `json:"user_name"`
}

func AddUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)

    var user NewUser
    err := decoder.Decode(&user)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    }
    user.UserID != NewUser.UserID{
        http.Error(w, "error", http.StatusBadRequest),
    }

}
```

Comment: I would argue you don't need that, you don't need to know whether or not the json matches the struct, all you need to know is whether or not the struct instance, into which you decoded that json, represents a valid instance of the "model". If however you're certain you need to constrain what comes through the wire to exactly match, *in structure*, some pre-defined schema, then you can't do it with the standard encoding/json library. You either have to look for a 3rd party lib, or implement your own json-structure-matching solution.

Comment: thanks for the insight!

Comment: You can't check if "JSON matches a struct". It's comparing apples to oranges. You can serialize a struct and see if the JSON you get matches the JSON you expect, or you can deserialize JSON into a struct and see if the struct you get matches the struct you expect. But comparing a struct to JSON is like comparing Argentina to apple pie.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this, with different levels of strictness:

- You can check if UserID and UserName are nonempty. This will not validate if the input matches the structure. It only captures the userid and name if those fields appear in the input.
- If empty values are acceptable, you can use `*string` instead of `string`, and check if the pointer is nil. If the pointer is nil, that field does not appear in the JSON, or it appears as nil. If it appears as empty string, the pointer will not be nil, but the string will be empty. This method also accepts if there are additional fields in the submitted JSON.
- For this specific case, if you want to make sure no additional unrecognized fields are passed, you can unmarshal the body into `interface{}`, and make sure it contains at most two fields, and that those are the fields you recognize.

In general if you need to do strict validation, you can use a json schema, and check if input validates against the schema you expect. This is usually more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response! ill give this a shot